# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error in DataTable.js

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have read all the previous threads concerning this topic, but still end up getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

in both Chrome and Internet Explorer. I have created an empty file, named it "DataTable.js" and copy-pasted the code from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

Then I added the following line at the end of the code where my table is built:

```
 $('#standard_report_table').DataTable();
```

My scripts:

```
    var buildStandardReportTable = function()
    {
        var divContent = "";

        var url = "/InputData/db_getSqlQueryResult";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,

            data: { sqlStr: "SELECT id, name_rus, visual_level, children_number, parent_id, effect_on_parent_id, lft, rgt, children_are_visible, report_type_id, font_color " +
                            "FROM report_entries_template_standard " + 
                            "WHERE visible = 1 AND report_type_id = " + $("#reportTypeCombobox").val() + ' ' +
                            "ORDER BY lft", connectionStr: "dbCon"},

            success: function (data)
            {

                var divContent = '';
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);           
                divContent = buildStandarReportContent(obj);

                //$('#choosenav1')[0].style.display = "block";
                //$('#choosenav2')[0].style.display = "block";
                //$('#choosenav3')[0].style.display = "block";

                $("#standard_report_table").html(divContent);
                $('#standard_report_table').DataTable();
            }
        })
    }
var buildStandarReportContent = function (obj)
{
    var divContent = '<thead border="0"><tr>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 30px"></th>';
    divContent += '<th style="width: 1000px;">Статья</th>';
    divContent += '<th>ID</th>';
    divContent += '</tr></thead>';
    // Table content

    divContent += '<tbody id="table_data">';         

    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
    {
        //'<tr class="' + (obj[i].Уровень == 1 ? "success" : "")
        //+ (obj[i].Уровень == 2 ? "warning" : "") + '"><td style="vertical-align: middle"><div style="margin-left:' + (obj[i].Уровень - 1) * 20 + 'px">' + obj[i].Статья_название + '</div></td>';
        divContent += '<tr style="height: 10px; background-color:' + obj[i].font_color + '" ' +
                           'onmouseover = "setElementsVisibility(' + i + ', 1)" ' +
                           'onmouseout = "setElementsVisibility(' + i + ', 0)">';

        divContent += '<td><div id = "add_child_sign' + i + '" style = "display : none";"><img src= "/Content/pics/plus_sign1.png" ' +
                                        'style= "height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "openAddNewChildWindow(' + obj[i].id + ')"</div></td>';
        divContent += '<td><div id = "delete_sign' + i + '" style = "display : none";"><img src= "/Content/pics/delete_sign1.png" ' +
                                        'style= "height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "deleteChild(' + obj[i].id + ')"</div></td>';
        divContent += '<td><div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" varia-hidden="true" id = "arrowup' + i + '" style = "' +
                                        'height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer; color:red" ' +
                                        'onclick = "swapChild(' + obj[i].id + ', \'up\')"></div>';
        divContent += '<td><div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" id = "arrowdown' + i + '" style = " ' +
                                        'height:10px; width:10px; cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "swapChild(' + obj[i].id + ', \'down\')"></div></td>';
        divContent += '<td><div id = "arrowleft' + i + '" style = "display : none";"><img src= "/Content/pics/arrowleft_sign1.png" ' +
                                        'style= "height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "editVisualLevel(' + obj[i].id + ', \'left\')"</div></td>';
        divContent += '<td><div id = "arrowright' + i + '" style = "display : none";"><img src= "/Content/pics/arrowright_sign1.png" ' +
                                        'style= "height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "editVisualLevel(' + obj[i].id + ', \'right\')"</div></td>';

        divContent += '<td><div id = "edit_sign' + i + '" style="display: none;"><div style = "vertical-align:bottom"><img src= "/Content/pics/edit_sign1.png" ' +
                                        'style= "height:10px;width:10px;cursor:pointer" ' +
                                        'onclick = "openEditChildWindow(' +
                                        obj[i].id + ',\'' + obj[i].name_rus + '\',\'' + obj[i].name + '\',' + obj[i].effect_on_parent_id + ',' +
                                        obj[i].parent_id + ',' + obj[i].report_type_id + ')"</div></td>';

        divContent += '<td><div class = "cell_level_' + obj[i].visual_level + '" style = "margin-left : ' + 30 * (obj[i].visual_level - 1) + 'px; ' +
                                   'cursor:' + (obj[i].children_number == 0 ? "default" : "pointer") + '" ' +
                                   'onclick="collapseTreeNode(' + obj[i].lft + ',' + obj[i].rgt + ',' + obj[i].children_are_visible + ','+ obj[i].children_number + ')">';
        divContent += obj[i].name_rus + '<span style="color:#A0A0A0; font-weight: normal;">&nbsp(' + obj[i].children_number + ')</span></div></td><td>' + obj[i].id + '</td><tr>';

    }

    divContent += '</tbody>'
    divContent += '</table>';
    return divContent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <table id="standard_report_table" class="table table-striped"></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your script

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code with the part where you actually use the `length` property.

Comment: Also, please post the markup where the #standard_report_table table is defined.

Comment: Please find the code attached. @RIYAJ KHAN, I don't see why you downgraded the question. The error actually raises in DataTable.js itself, and the "length" does not seem to appear in my code. Anyway...would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan You don't know who downvoted you. Please note that all those comments (and presumably the downvote) happened before your question contained any code or useful details. Downvotes or close votes were completely appropriate at the time.

Comment: Then what was the reason for that, @PayRoub ? I just want to get to know the rules of the site so that I don't loose votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in this way.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('#standard_report_table').DataTable({
    "ajax": obj
});
```

define html

```
<table id="standard_report_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: the error of length is resolved now, but I get a warning of invalid JSON object suggesting to visit http://datatables.net/nt/1, though the my object worked perfectly before binding DataTable and it also passed validation test at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please paste your json

Comment: [{"id":983,"name_rus":"EVA","visual_level":1,"children_number":3,"parent_id":null,"effect_on_parent_id":2,"lft":1,"rgt":162,"children_are_visible":true,"report_type_id":1,"font_color":null},{"id":985,"name_rus":"NOPLAT","visual_level":2,"children_number":4,"parent_id":983,"effect_on_parent_id":2,"lft":2,"rgt":107,"children_are_visible":true,"report_type_id":1,"font_color":null}]

Comment: Take look this example.https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html